# Printing contents of map item in dynamodb with python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am attempting to print the value of "age" in stored in the info attribute within a dynamodb.   Below is a sample data set along with the code I am using.  I recieve an error:  "KeyERROR: 'info.age'.   I have tried several different variations and all unsuccessful.

Here is code where I query the database and try to print output:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('bourbon_id').eq("Four Roses") )

for i in response['Items']:
    print(i['bourbon_id'], ":", i['source_id'], ":", i['info.age'])
```

Here is example data:

```
"bourbon_id": "Four Roses",
"source_id": "Liquor Barn",
"info":{
    "age": 11,      
    "proof": 124,
    "open": 1,
    "closed": 0,
    "barrled": "June 12 2002",
    "bottled": "December 15 2013",
    "description": "OESK"
```

If I remove the age, it prints out all items within info..   How can I get just the value of age to print?

```
for i in response['Items']:
    print(i['bourbon_id'], ":", i['source_id'], ":", i['info'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for referencing items in dict in your case is `i["info"]["age"]`. Python doesn't have dot notation for accessing members of a dict.